# Using listings with multiple languages, define language as LaTeX gives error

Tags: listings

I'm documenting a system which produces PDF files from database entries using Python, and I'm using the listing package to insert the code via `\lstinputlisting`. Everything has worked fine 'till I got to the latex code. I can use `\lstinputlisting[language=TeX]{myfile.tex}` and it works fine, but if I use `\lstinputlisting[language=[LaTeX]TeX]{myfile.tex}` it will output `Package Listings Error: File 'T(.tex)' not found. \lstinputlisting[language=[LaTeX]T`. How can I fix it?

A MWE (or sort of, since it relies on the source code being on an external file and the languages defs are not so minimal) would be:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish]{layout}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{editorGray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{editorOcher}{rgb}{1, 0.5, 0} % #FF7F00 -> rgb(239, 169, 0)
\definecolor{editorGreen}{rgb}{0, 0.5, 0} % #007C00 -> rgb(0, 124, 0)

\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    morekeywords={break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete,         do, else, false, finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, null, return, switch, this, throw, true, try, typeof, var, void, while, with},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morecomment=[l]//,
    morestring=[b]",
    morestring=[b]'
}
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS}{
    keywords={accelerator,azimuth,background,background-attachment,
        background-color,background-image,background-position,
        background-position-x,background-position-y,background-repeat,
        behavior,border,border-bottom,border-bottom-color,
        border-bottom-style,border-bottom-width,border-collapse,
        border-color,border-left,border-left-color,border-left-style,
        border-left-width,border-right,border-right-color,
        border-right-style,border-right-width,border-spacing,
        border-style,border-top,border-top-color,border-top-style,
        border-top-width,border-width,bottom,caption-side,clear,
        clip,color,content,counter-increment,counter-reset,cue,
        cue-after,cue-before,cursor,direction,display,elevation,
        empty-cells,filter,float,font,font-family,font-size,
        font-size-adjust,font-stretch,font-style,font-variant,
        font-weight,height,ime-mode,include-source,
        layer-background-color,layer-background-image,layout-flow,
        layout-grid,layout-grid-char,layout-grid-char-spacing,
        layout-grid-line,layout-grid-mode,layout-grid-type,left,
        letter-spacing,line-break,line-height,list-style,
        list-style-image,list-style-position,list-style-type,margin,
        margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,
        marker-offset,marks,max-height,max-width,min-height,
        min-width,-moz-binding,-moz-border-radius,
        -moz-border-radius-topleft,-moz-border-radius-topright,
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft,
        -moz-border-top-colors,-moz-border-right-colors,
        -moz-border-bottom-colors,-moz-border-left-colors,-moz-opacity,
        -moz-outline,-moz-outline-color,-moz-outline-style,
        -moz-outline-width,-moz-user-focus,-moz-user-input,
        -moz-user-modify,-moz-user-select,orphans,outline,
        outline-color,outline-style,outline-width,overflow,
        overflow-X,overflow-Y,padding,padding-bottom,padding-left,
        padding-right,padding-top,page,page-break-after,
        page-break-before,page-break-inside,pause,pause-after,
        pause-before,pitch,pitch-range,play-during,position,quotes,
        -replace,richness,right,ruby-align,ruby-overhang,
        ruby-position,-set-link-source,size,speak,speak-header,
        speak-numeral,speak-punctuation,speech-rate,stress,
        scrollbar-arrow-color,scrollbar-base-color,
        scrollbar-dark-shadow-color,scrollbar-face-color,
        scrollbar-highlight-color,scrollbar-shadow-color,
        scrollbar-3d-light-color,scrollbar-track-color,table-layout,
        text-align,text-align-last,text-decoration,text-indent,
        text-justify,text-overflow,text-shadow,text-transform,
        text-autospace,text-kashida-space,text-underline-position,top,
        unicode-bidi,-use-link-source,vertical-align,visibility,
        voice-family,volume,white-space,widows,width,word-break,
        word-spacing,word-wrap,writing-mode,z-index,zoom},  
    sensitive=true,
    morecomment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    morestring=[b]',
    morestring=[b]",
    alsoletter={:},
    alsodigit={-}
}
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
    language=html,
    sensitive=true, 
    alsoletter={<>=-},
    otherkeywords={
        % HTML tags
        <, </, >,
        </a, <a, </a>,
        </abbr, <abbr, </abbr>,
        </address, <address, </address>,
        </area, <area, </area>,
        </area, <area, </area>,
        </article, <article, </article>,
        </aside, <aside, </aside>,
        </audio, <audio, </audio>,
        </audio, <audio, </audio>,
        </b, <b, </b>,
        </base, <base, </base>,
        </bdi, <bdi, </bdi>,
        </bdo, <bdo, </bdo>,
        </blockquote, <blockquote, </blockquote>,
        </body, <body, </body>,
        </br, <br, </br>,
        </button, <button, </button>,
        </canvas, <canvas, </canvas>,
        </caption, <caption, </caption>,
        </cite, <cite, </cite>,
        </code, <code, </code>,
        </col, <col, </col>,
        </colgroup, <colgroup, </colgroup>,
        </data, <data, </data>,
        </datalist, <datalist, </datalist>,
        </dd, <dd, </dd>,
        </del, <del, </del>,
        </details, <details, </details>,
        </dfn, <dfn, </dfn>,
        </div, <div, </div>,
        </dl, <dl, </dl>,
        </dt, <dt, </dt>,
        </em, <em, </em>,
        </embed, <embed, </embed>,
        </fieldset, <fieldset, </fieldset>,
        </figcaption, <figcaption, </figcaption>,
        </figure, <figure, </figure>,
        </footer, <footer, </footer>,
        </form, <form, </form>,
        </h1, <h1, </h1>,
        </h2, <h2, </h2>,
        </h3, <h3, </h3>,
        </h4, <h4, </h4>,
        </h5, <h5, </h5>,
        </h6, <h6, </h6>,
        </head, <head, </head>,
        </header, <header, </header>,
        </hr, <hr, </hr>,
        </html, <html, </html>,
        </i, <i, </i>,
        </iframe, <iframe, </iframe>,
        </img, <img, </img>,
        </input, <input, </input>,
        </ins, <ins, </ins>,
        </kbd, <kbd, </kbd>,
        </keygen, <keygen, </keygen>,
        </label, <label, </label>,
        </legend, <legend, </legend>,
        </li, <li, </li>,
        </link, <link, </link>,
        </main, <main, </main>,
        </map, <map, </map>,
        </mark, <mark, </mark>,
        </math, <math, </math>,
        </menu, <menu, </menu>,
        </menuitem, <menuitem, </menuitem>,
        </meta, <meta, </meta>,
        </meter, <meter, </meter>,
        </nav, <nav, </nav>,
        </noscript, <noscript, </noscript>,
        </object, <object, </object>,
        </ol, <ol, </ol>,
        </optgroup, <optgroup, </optgroup>,
        </option, <option, </option>,
        </output, <output, </output>,
        </p, <p, </p>,
        </param, <param, </param>,
        </pre, <pre, </pre>,
        </progress, <progress, </progress>,
        </q, <q, </q>,
        </rp, <rp, </rp>,
        </rt, <rt, </rt>,
        </ruby, <ruby, </ruby>,
        </s, <s, </s>,
        </samp, <samp, </samp>,
        </script, <script, </script>,
        </section, <section, </section>,
        </select, <select, </select>,
        </small, <small, </small>,
        </source, <source, </source>,
        </span, <span, </span>,
        </strong, <strong, </strong>,
        </style, <style, </style>,
        </summary, <summary, </summary>,
        </sup, <sup, </sup>,
        </svg, <svg, </svg>,
        </table, <table, </table>,
        </tbody, <tbody, </tbody>,
        </td, <td, </td>,
        </template, <template, </template>,
        </textarea, <textarea, </textarea>,
        </tfoot, <tfoot, </tfoot>,
        </th, <th, </th>,
        </thead, <thead, </thead>,
        </time, <time, </time>,
        </title, <title, </title>,
        </tr, <tr, </tr>,
        </track, <track, </track>,
        </u, <u, </u>,
        </ul, <ul, </ul>,
        </var, <var, </var>,
        </video, <video, </video>,
        </wbr, <wbr, </wbr>,
        />, <!
    },  
    ndkeywords={
        % General
        =,
        % HTML attributes
        accept=, accept-charset=, accesskey=, action=, align=, alt=, async=, autocomplete=, autofocus=, autoplay=, autosave=, bgcolor=, border=, buffered=, challenge=, charset=, checked=, cite=, class=, code=, codebase=, color=, cols=, colspan=, content=, contenteditable=, contextmenu=, controls=, coords=, data=, datetime=, default=, defer=, dir=, dirname=, disabled=, download=, draggable=, dropzone=, enctype=, for=, form=, formaction=, headers=, height=, hidden=, high=, href=, hreflang=, http-equiv=, icon=, id=, ismap=, itemprop=, keytype=, kind=, label=, lang=, language=, list=, loop=, low=, manifest=, max=, maxlength=, media=, method=, min=, multiple=, name=, novalidate=, open=, optimum=, pattern=, ping=, placeholder=, poster=, preload=, pubdate=, radiogroup=, readonly=, rel=, required=, reversed=, rows=, rowspan=, sandbox=, scope=, scoped=, seamless=, selected=, shape=, size=, sizes=, span=, spellcheck=, src=, srcdoc=, srclang=, start=, step=, style=, summary=, tabindex=, target=, title=, type=, usemap=, value=, width=, wrap=,
        % CSS properties
        accelerator:,azimuth:,background:,background-attachment:,
        background-color:,background-image:,background-position:,
        background-position-x:,background-position-y:,background-repeat:,
        behavior:,border:,border-bottom:,border-bottom-color:,
        border-bottom-style:,border-bottom-width:,border-collapse:,
        border-color:,border-left:,border-left-color:,border-left-style:,
        border-left-width:,border-right:,border-right-color:,
        border-right-style:,border-right-width:,border-spacing:,
        border-style:,border-top:,border-top-color:,border-top-style:,
        border-top-width:,border-width:,bottom:,caption-side:,clear:,
        clip:,color:,content:,counter-increment:,counter-reset:,cue:,
        cue-after:,cue-before:,cursor:,direction:,display:,elevation:,
        empty-cells:,filter:,float:,font:,font-family:,font-size:,
        font-size-adjust:,font-stretch:,font-style:,font-variant:,
        font-weight:,height:,ime-mode:,include-source:,
        layer-background-color:,layer-background-image:,layout-flow:,
        layout-grid:,layout-grid-char:,layout-grid-char-spacing:,
        layout-grid-line:,layout-grid-mode:,layout-grid-type:,left:,
        letter-spacing:,line-break:,line-height:,list-style:,
        list-style-image:,list-style-position:,list-style-type:,margin:,
        margin-bottom:,margin-left:,margin-right:,margin-top:,
        marker-offset:,marks:,max-height:,max-width:,min-height:,
        min-width:,transition-duration:,transition-property:,
        transition-timing-function:,transform:,
        -moz-transform:,-moz-binding:,-moz-border-radius:,
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:,-moz-border-radius-topright:,
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:,
        -moz-border-top-colors:,-moz-border-right-colors:,
        -moz-border-bottom-colors:,-moz-border-left-colors:,-moz-opacity:,
        -moz-outline:,-moz-outline-color:,-moz-outline-style:,
        -moz-outline-width:,-moz-user-focus:,-moz-user-input:,
        -moz-user-modify:,-moz-user-select:,orphans:,outline:,
        outline-color:,outline-style:,outline-width:,overflow:,
        overflow-X:,overflow-Y:,padding:,padding-bottom:,padding-left:,
        padding-right:,padding-top:,page:,page-break-after:,
        page-break-before:,page-break-inside:,pause:,pause-after:,
        pause-before:,pitch:,pitch-range:,play-during:,position:,quotes:,
        -replace:,richness:,right:,ruby-align:,ruby-overhang:,
        ruby-position:,-set-link-source:,size:,speak:,speak-header:,
        speak-numeral:,speak-punctuation:,speech-rate:,stress:,
        scrollbar-arrow-color:,scrollbar-base-color:,
        scrollbar-dark-shadow-color:,scrollbar-face-color:,
        scrollbar-highlight-color:,scrollbar-shadow-color:,
        scrollbar-3d-light-color:,scrollbar-track-color:,table-layout:,
        text-align:,text-align-last:,text-decoration:,text-indent:,
        text-justify:,text-overflow:,text-shadow:,text-transform:,
        text-autospace:,text-kashida-space:,text-underline-position:,top:,
        unicode-bidi:,-use-link-source:,vertical-align:,visibility:,
        voice-family:,volume:,white-space:,widows:,width:,word-break:,
        word-spacing:,word-wrap:,writing-mode:,z-index:,zoom:
    },  
    morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
    tag=[s]
}
\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorGray},
    basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    %xleftmargin={0.75cm},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design   
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
    %commentstyle=\color{darkgray}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{editorGreen}\ttfamily,
    ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorGreen}\bfseries,
    stringstyle=\color{editorOcher},
    % Code
    language=HTML5,
    alsolanguage=JavaScript,
    alsodigit={.:;},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    literate={Á}{{\'A}}1 {á}{{\'a}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1
            {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1 {°}{{\degree}}1 {•}{{\textbullet}}1 {“}{{``}}1 {”}{{''}}1,
    title=\lstname
}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=[LaTeX]TeX]{myfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with `language={[LaTeX]TeX}` just add braces.

Comment: @salimbou You should post it as an answer. I already gave mine, but yours is more concise. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I solved it defining a dummy language:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{template}{
    language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
    sensitive=true
}
```

What i'd like now is to have a different style for it... guess I'll have to post that on another question.

Comment: Did you post that other question?  I'm hitting that problem now.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
\lstinputlisting[ language={[LaTeX]TeX} ] {myfile.tex}
```

Observe the language setting using curly braces {}